# Emoticons missing in Notes client

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, richtext

I created a xPage using the RichText control (ckEditor) boundet to a notes richtext field. Within this control users can select an emoticon from the icon. This icon is saved within the richText item Body:

```
<p dir="ltr">
    <img alt="Lachend" height="18" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/domino/ckeditor/plugins/sametimeemoticons/images/EmoticonLaugh.gif" title="Lachend" width="18" /></p>
<p dir="ltr">
```

but is not visible within the lotus notes client if you open the docuement with a form.

Is there any way to display the Icon within the RichText field? I do not want to use a xPage for the notes client.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for full fidelity between XPages and traditional Notes Client? I'm afraid that's not possible without third party products like CoexEdit from Genii Software (note, I've not used that, but I know Ben Langhinrichs has considerable experience on rich text fidelity, but there may be other products available).